Acceso directo no actualiza base
Tengo un programita que funciona muy bien pero a un usuario se le ocurrió crear un acceso directo al escritorio y al hacerlo, se ejecuta, consulta la base, pero no la actualiza. Al principio pensé que era por un problema de conexión con la base pero resulta que el botón de consulta trae los resultados correcto, con lo cual entiendo que la conexión existe y funciona. Sólo no la actualiza (no agrega nuevos elementos) y no sé por qué.
Copio aquí debajo el código por si pueden ayudarme a resolverlo:
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="azure")

def crear_base():
    la_base = sqlite3.connect("milocal2.db")
    return la_base


def crear_tabla(la_base):
    cursor = la_base.cursor()
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, producto)"
cursor.execute(sql)
la_base.commit()


la_base = crear_base()
crear_tabla(la_base)


def insertar(producto):
cursor = la_base.cursor()
data = (producto, )
sql = "INSERT INTO stock(producto) VALUES(?)"
cursor.execute(sql, data)
la_base.commit()

def listar():

cursor = la_base.cursor()

registros = tree.get_children()
for elemento in registros:
    tree.delete(elemento)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM stock")
for fila in cursor:
    tree.insert("", "end", text=fila[0], values=(fila[1]))

producto = StringVar()

product = Label(root, text="Producto")
product.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
product = Entry(root, textvariable=producto, width=25)
product.grid(row=3, column=0)


tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree["columns"] = ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")

tree.column("#0", width=50, minwidth=50, anchor=W)
tree.column("#1", width=80, minwidth=80, anchor=W)

tree.heading("#0", text="Id", anchor=W)
tree.heading("#1", text="Producto", anchor=W)


tree.grid(column=0, row=18, columnspan=5)

boton_a = Button(
root,
text="Alta",
background="steel blue",
width=20,
command=lambda: insertar(
    producto.get(),)

boton_a.grid(row=3, column=5)

boton_bd = Button(
root,
text="Mostrar",
background="steel blue",
width=20,
command=listar,)
boton_bd.grid(row=17, column=2)

root.mainloop()

(Sé que hay que emprolijarlo, sepan disculpar).
Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Hola Diego, supongo que el SO es Windows, ¿distribuyes el script/paquete directamente o usas algún freezer como PyInstaller? Ten en cuenta que con tu código  la BD se buscará o creará en el CWD. Prueba con
la_base = sqlite3.connect(Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("milocal2.db").absolute()) importando pathlib.Path previamente con from pathlib import Path

¡Hola FJSevilla! Efectivamente el SO es Windows. Utilizo PyInstaller para la creación del ejecutable. He probado tu solución pero ni siquiera crea la base (ojo, la he copiado tal cual la has escrito).
